# Error in importing 3D mesh generated from gmsh into fipy

Tags: python, mesh, fipy

I am having a lot trouble importing 3D mesh from `gmsh` to `fipy`. I have looked through all the questions regarding `gmsh` and `fipy` on this forum, but unfortunately I didn't find a similar topic.

I am importing a 3D cylindrical mesh generated by `gmsh 4.0` into FiPy. I am currently using python 2.7, and my operation system is Windows 10,  64-bit.

According to `fipy` manual, the Gmsh3D function should convert the `gmsh` mesh into a `fipy` mesh, and thus I wrote:

```
from fipy import * 

mesh = Gmsh3D('C:\Users\William\Documents\Python Scripts\cylinder3.msh')
```

In addition, my Gmsh exe, the mesh (cylinder.msh) as well as my python code are all located in the same directory.

However, I kept getting "[Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". I am attaching the full error message below. Anyone experienced and have solved this issue? Any pointer is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Full error message:

```
runfile('C:/Users/William/Documents/Python Scripts/cylinder1.py', wdir='C:/Users/William/Documents/Python Scripts')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-1-c2ebfb9899c3>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/William/Documents/Python Scripts/cylinder1.py', wdir='C:/Users/William/Documents/Python Scripts')

File "C:\Users\William\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\William\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 93, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "C:/Users/William/Documents/Python Scripts/cylinder1.py", line 23, in <module>
    mesh = Gmsh3D('C:\Users\William\Documents\Python Scripts\cylinder3.msh')

File "C:\Users\William\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py", line 1944, in __init__
    self._orderedCellVertexIDs_data) = self.mshFile.read()

File "C:\Users\William\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py", line 853, in read
    os.unlink(self.elemsPath)

WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\william\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmp1bhyl6Elements'
```

Comment: Do you have any software that's somehow managing to access the temporary file immediately after it's being created (like an antivirus suite)?

Comment: Does this only happen with `Gmsh3D`? Have you tried 2D meshes? Does, e.g., [`examples/diffusion/circle.py`](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.circle.html) work?

Answer (score 0):

FiPy 3.3 resolved some issues with Gmsh on Windows. Please upgrade and let us know if you are still having issues.